# Unit Testing for async Task<ActionResult>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc

I am very new to ASP.NET CORE MVC and I was wondering if anyone could help me about my problem.

I was working in a project that will get all projects within a specific azure devops organization.

Here is my controller code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Organization(string selectedOrg, string oauth)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    IndexViewModel model = new IndexViewModel();
    model.Organizations = OrganizationData.Data;
    if (selectedOrg == null)
    {
        selectedOrg = model.Organizations.FirstOrDefault().OrgName;
    }
    else
    {
        model.SelectedOrg = selectedOrg;
    }
    var token = _cache.Get<TokenModel>("Token" + HttpContext.Session.GetString("TokenGuid"));
    oauth = token.AccessToken;
    var url = "https://dev.azure.com/" + selectedOrg + "/_apis/projects?api-version=4.1";
    try
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", oauth);

        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        var responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        model.Projects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProjectsModel>(responseBody);

        client.Dispose();
        return View("Index", model);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        client.Dispose();
        return Json(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(e.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Can anyone help how to do unit testing with this one? Or do I have to refactor this one?

Comment: The code however  is tightly coupled to implementation concerns that would not allow it to be unit tested in isolation. Ideally you want to be able to mock/stub all dependencies and inject them into the subject under test.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on this one. Is it possible to have a unit test with just for the json result?

Comment: You would need to abstract out the http call so you can fake the json response.

Comment: I also just realized you are mixing blocking `.Result` with async-await, which can lead to deadlocks.

Comment: How can I abstract the http call? Can you please help me with this?

Comment: This is quite difficult to answer, due to there being a number of problems to look at. First, change `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` to `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` to address the `.Result` problem as mentioned by @nkosi. Then use your favourite search engine to learn about why it's a bad idea to create `HttpClient`s like that and how you might want to use dependency injection instead. Lastly, by abstraction, @nkosi *likely* means create another class that handles making the request to your Azure endpoint and inject that into your controller.

Comment: You can create a test, check step 7 o 8 in this guide: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264219/Creating-Web-API-in-ASP-NET-Core-2-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **way** to many dependencies.

Why does the signature of the method pass an `oauth` value that is never used?

First off, calling any external dependency via http inside a controller should be frowned upon.  This whole thing should be abstracted into it's own call.  Since it appears to be getting data, this should actually be at your data tier.  Covering a whole n-tier approach with separate projects is most likely out of scope, so lets just cover the bare minimum for unit testing **in my opinion**.

First you need to abstract your HttpClient.  You can't really do unit test methods if they make any calls outside themselves (for the most part) because then it's not a unit test, it's an integration test.

```
// I don't have a full grasp of your complete eco-system so based on the
// minimal information provided, this would at least get you close
public interface IAzureAPI
{
  public Task<string> GetOrgAsync(string org, string oauth);
}

public class AzureAPI : IDisposable
{
  public async Task<string> GetOrgAsync(string org, string oauth)
  {
    // use *using* not try/catch/finally/dispose
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", oauth);

      var url = "https://dev.azure.com/" + org+ "/_apis/projects?api-version=4.1";

      var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
      // never use `.Result` unless you absolutely know what you are doing
      // always using async/wait if possible
      var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
      return result;
   }
  }
}
```

Hopefully you are using a DI Framework:

```
public class MyController
{
  private IAzureAPI _azureAPI;
  public MyController(IAzureAPI azureAPI)
  {
    _azureAPI = azureAPI;
  }
}
```

Now onto the hard part:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Organization(string selectedOrg, string oauth)
{
    IndexViewModel model = new IndexViewModel();

    // I have no idea where model came from so
    // this appears to block "unit-testing"
    // strange that you don't validate `selectedOrg`, you just use it
    model.Organizations = OrganizationData.Data;
    if (selectedOrg == null)
    {
        selectedOrg = model.Organizations.FirstOrDefault().OrgName;
    }
    else
    {
        model.SelectedOrg = selectedOrg;
    }

    // no idea where `_cache` came from so 
    // also appears to block "unit-testing"
    // As does `HttpContext` because you aren't using the
    // Interface
    var token = _cache.Get<TokenModel>("Token" + HttpContext.Session.GetString("TokenGuid"));
    oauth = token.AccessToken;

    try
    {
        var orgInfo = await _azureAPI.GetOrgAsync(selectedOrg, oauth);

        model.Projects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProjectsModel>(orgInfo);

        // return a view here???
        return View("Index", model);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // return JSON here instead????
        return Json(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(e.ToString()));
    }
}
```

That's a general start, but there are too many unknowns, and to many dependencies to actually write a real unit test.  Here is a quick structure and semi-test based on the information you've provided.

```
public MyControllerTests
{
  // for 100% Cover Coverage you'd need all of these
  public async Task Organization_OrgAsString_ReturnsView
  {
    //...
  }

  public async Task Organization_OrgAsNull_ReturnsView
  {
    // Arrange
    var azureAPI = Substitute.For<IAzureAPI>();
    azureAPI.GetOrgAsync(null, null)
      .Returns("somestring");
    var controller = new MyController(azureAPI);

    // Act
    var result = await controller.Organization(null, null);

    // Assert
    Assert.That(result....);

  }

  public async Task Organization_WithException_ReturnsJson
  {
    //...
  }

}
```

Comment: With Nsubstitute you don't need explicitly return `Task` for asynchronous methods: `azureAPI.GetOrgAsync(null, null).Returns("somestring");`